# Error de compilación: final extra

Tags: pascal

Quiero hacer una calculadora para la universidad, que me permita elegir qué es lo que quiero hacer, pero no funciona. Quiero compilar y me sale que tengo un final extra. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Éste es el código:

```
Program Conversor_de_unidades;

uses crt;

var a, b, opcion: integer;

begin
    clrscr;
    write('introduzca un valor: ');
    readln(a);
    Write('introduzca otra ves unvalor');
    readln(b);


    writeln('seleccione su opcion');
    writeln('1: sumar');
    writeln('2: restar');
    readln(opcion);

    case opcion of
        1: writeln('a+b: ', (a+(b);
        2: writeln('a-b: ', (a-(b);


    end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

A si, a priori,

- No usas las variables "a" y "b"
- Falta controlar y inicializar variables
- El problema por que no compilaba, era porque faltaban algunos paréntesis(demasiados paréntesis innecesarios).

---

```
Program Conversor_de_unidades;
uses crt;
var a, b, opcion: integer;
begin

 writeln('seleccione su opcion');
 writeln('1: sumar');
 writeln('2: restar');
 readln(opcion);
 writeln('Introcuce el valor a:');
 readln(a);
 writeln('Introcuce el valor b:');
 readln(b);

 case opcion of
  1: writeln('a+b: ', (a+(b)));
  2: writeln('a-b: ', (a-(b)));
 end;
end.
```